# Enable editing a field in Django admin's list view

Tags: django, django-admin

Consider a model that stores application forms. I would like to use Django admin to quickly view applications *and change their status*. I would like to be able to change the status of an application right in the view listing all the applications without having to open each application for editing. So, is it possible to make a field editable right in the admin list view?

Comment: It is supported by django admin: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable

Comment: @Tonio This is the answer. Thanks!